# Reading and Setting Up CSV files on R Programming Language

Tags: r, csv, statistics

I would like to clarify my understanding here on both converting a file into CSV and also reading it.  Let's use a dataset from R for instance, titled longley.

To set up a data frame, I can just use the write.table command as follows, right?

```
d1<-longley 
write.table(d1, file="", sep="1,16", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)
```

Has this already become a data frame or am I missing something here?
Now let's say if I want to read this CSV file.  Then would my code be something like:

```
read.table(<dframe1>, header=FALSE, sep="", quote="\"")
```

It seems like before that I have to use a function called setwd().  I'm not really sure what it does or how it helps.  Can someone help me here?

Comment: Have you tried typing `?setwd` from the command line?

Comment: Also, what do you expect `sep="1,16"` to do??

Comment: yes, I did.  I'm not sure what the input is though and I'm also not sure what this would be doing for my code.

Answer (score 1):

`longley` and, therefore, `d1` are already data frames (type `class(d1)` in the console). A data frame is a fundamental data structure in R. Writing a data frame to a file saves the data in the data frame. In this case, you're trying to save the data in the data frame in CSV format, which you would do like this:

```
write.csv(d1, "myFileName.csv")
```

`write.csv` is a wrapper for `write.table` that takes care of the settings needed for saving in CSV format. You could also do:

```
write.table(d1, "myFileName.csv", sep=",")
```

`sep=","` tells R to write the file with values separated by a comma.

Then, to read the file into an R session you can do this:

```
df = read.csv("myFileName.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This creates a new object called `df`, which is the data frame created from the data in `myFileName.csv`. Once again, `read.csv` is a wrapper for `read.table` that takes care of the settings for reading a CSV file.

`setwd` is how you change the working directory--that is, the default directory where R writes to and reads from. But you can also keep the current working directory unchanged and just give `write.csv` or `read.csv` (or any other function that writes or reads R objects) the full path to wherever you want to read from or write to. For example:

```
write.csv(d1, "/path/for/saving/file/myFileName.csv")
```